# What's the currency on the right of Nova in Starlink: Battle for Atlas?

Tags: starlink

I have been playing Starlink: Battle for Atlas on Nintendo Switch for a while now, and I just can't seem to figure out what the currency on the right of the Nova is.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean with "on the right of the Nova"? It seems [Nova](https://starlink.fandom.com/wiki/Nova) *is* the currency.

Answer (score 2):

While a screenshot (or even just a *description*) would help **massively**, and it's been a while since I picked up my copy of Starlink, there are 3 Currencies in the game.

The first two have been in the game since release:

- [Electrum](https://starlink.fandom.com/wiki/Electrum), listed in Yellow.  You receive shipments of Electrum from your Prospector allies.  Easy to obtain, spent in large numbers.
- [Nova](https://starlink.fandom.com/wiki/Nova), listed in Blue.  You get this from bosses or missions, and it is your early-game bottleneck.

The third was added by the free "Crimson Moon" update in April 2019:

- [Cogs](https://starlink.fandom.com/wiki/Cogs), listed in Purple.  You get this from Outlaws, or missions on the Crimson Moon.  You can spend it on paint-jobs, or Nova.

(Unless they've added a fourth type since I last played)